# ASP.NET MVC 5 Identity attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So i am doing a MVC 5 application using the individual user accounts authentication method. I can see that the framework created the ASP.net.Users  table for me with a bunch of information. My question is simple:

Is this table the equivelent of having a, say, User class with such attributes ? and where are those attributes initialized in the code??? i can't seem to find any information about this specific topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its using EntityFramework Code first,
the class ApplicationDbContext in file "IdentityModels.cs" under the Models Folder
extends `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`
that the ApplicationUser is the POCO for AspNetUsers table in your database

Comment: so that class is my "User" ?

Comment: it's making more sense now. I really needed to understand this because i need to explain it in my Relational Model and i have a bunch of other data i need to insert.

Comment: yes,ApplicationUser is your "User" class. and you can Add any property in that class. the point you should know is that any class can be your user class that extends "IdentityUser" class.

Answer (score 0):

Created by EF code first Go to IdentityConfig in App_Start folder to find out more:

take a look [at this](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity) to know more about user identity management in MVC 5.

**UPDATE**

For the properties that you can look at:
[add to the user profile](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594)

Comment: yeah i've read that topic. maybe i am not understing it at all :P.

Comment: but all i see in that class are a bunch of methods to create users. not their attributes initialized

Comment: // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
   this is extracted from the ApplicationUser class in your app!